# How to run only one job at time in same laravel queue?

Tags: laravel, queue

I have saas service which working with API. It has limits so I need that one user account doing only one request at the same time.

For this I queuing with `OnQueue($user->name);`

then in `handle()` doing job...

I need only one job can be run in users queue. At the same time may be run only diffent queues 1 job per 1 queue.

Im using redis connection.

This my job class:

```
 public function __construct(Accounts $acc)
    {
        $this->acc = $acc;
        $this->ownjob = $acc->prepareJobQueue();
    }

    public function handle()
    {
        $acc = $this->acc;
        $job = $this->ownjob;

        $api = new Api([
            'login'     => $acc->login,
            'password'  => $acc->password,
        ]);
        if ($api->checkLogin()) {
            info("{$acc->login} OK Authorized");
            foreach ($job['queue'] as $term) {
                switch($term['type']) {
                    case 'hashtag':
                        info("{$acc->login} Queuing: type - {$term['type']}, value - {$term['value']}");
                        $hashtag = Hashtags::where('cha_name',$term['value'])->first();
                        $answer = $api->getUsersByHashtag($hashtag,50);
                        break;
                    case 'concurency':
                        info("{$acc->login} Queuing: type - {$term['type']}, value - {$term['value']}");
                        $soc_user = Users::where('soc_unique_id',$term['value'])->first();
                        $answer = $api->getUserFollowers($soc_user);
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
            }
        } else {
            info("{$acc->login} NOT Authorized - STOP JOB");
        }

    }
```

This is how I dispatching job:

```
$accounts = Accounts::select(['id', 'login', 'hashtag_filter', 'concurency_filter'])->whereNotNull('hashtag_filter')->get();
        foreach ($accounts as $acc) {
            doFollowing::dispatch($acc)->onQueue($acc->login);
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use Laravel's builtin rate limiting for this (note that it does require Redis).

Inside your job:

```
Redis::funnel('process-name')->limit(1)->then(function () {
    // Your job logic here
});
```

Note that if you don't provide a second callback to then, it will throw an exception if it cannot obtain the lock (which will cause your job to fail)

If you're using Laravel 6 or higher you could also opt to do this in a job middleware, rather than in the job itself (handy if you have multiple jobs that share the same lock)

More info on Laravel's rate limiting: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queues#rate-limiting

Answer (score 2):

#### Use [mxl/laravel-queue-rate-limit](https://github.com/mxl/laravel-queue-rate-limit) Composer package.

It enables you to rate limit Laravel jobs on specific queue without using A third party driver such as `Redis`.

1. Install it with:

   ```
   $ composer require mxl/laravel-queue-rate-limit:^1.0
   ```
2. This package is compatible with Laravel 5.5+ and uses [auto-discovery][1] feature to add `MichaelLedin\LaravelQueueRateLimit\QueueServiceProvider::class` to providers.
3. Add rate limit (x number of jobs per y seconds) settings to `config/queue.php`:

   ```
   'rateLimit' => [
       'mail' => [
           'allows' => 1, // number of jobs
           'every' => 5 // time interval in seconds
       ]
   ]
   ```

   These settings allow to run 1 job every 5 seconds on `mail` queue.
   Make sure that default queue driver (`default` property in `config/queue.php`) is set to any value except `sync`.
4. Run queue worker with `--queue mail` option:

   ```
   $ php artisan queue:work --queue mail
   ```

   You can run worker on multiple queues, but only queues referenced in `rateLimit` setting will be rate limited:

   ```
   $ php artisan queue:work --queue mail,default
   ```

   Jobs on `default` queue will be executed without rate limiting.
5. Queue some jobs to test rate limiting:

   ```
   SomeJob::dispatch()->onQueue('mail');
   SomeJob::dispatch()->onQueue('mail');
   SomeJob::dispatch()->onQueue('mail');
   SomeJob::dispatch();
   ```

Comment: I have dynamic queue naming as it's queue per user - I can't always modyfing config for each user. Also Im asking not about limit per time, I want simultaneously run only one job in same queue - does't matter it will be 1 per minute or 100

Answer (score 1):

You could limit `numprocs` per queue in your Supervisor or Horizon setup.

If you only spawn one queue worker per user I believe you will get your desired behaviour.

Comment: It will good work when users is ~100, but what if users 10k? Also as I said - queue name is user name. In your variant I need always modyfing supervisor config?